# Is there a code for clicked divs?

Tags: html, css, button, click

I was wondering if there is a code for something like this:

```
.element, #element {
    top:20px;
    right:20px;
    width:25px;
    height:10px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.4s ease-out;}

.element:hover, #element:hover {
    opacity:1;}
```

This is the element, and it's a clickable button (button is in the basic code of the website), and I'm now wondering if there's a css code for a clicked button. Would it be .element:activated or something like that? I only know this from `a`s and I don't know if it would also work with buttons, because I want to change its `width` when clicking it.

```
.element:activated {
    width:10px;}
```

for example like this. thank you!

Comment: You can actually turn a radio button into that by means of ccs only, so without javascript. There are many examples for that on google.

Comment: No, if you want actual states, you need JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is infact. It is the extension `:active`

The css styling under `active` will be run if you click or activate the element.

In your example, you would want:

```
.element:active, #element:active{
    width:10px; // This will be run when you click on the element
}
```

If you would like the button to stay on permanently after you click it you can slip this javascript in (Uses Jquery):

```
$('#element').on('click', function(){
    $('#element').css("width", "10");
});
```